# Getting error in apche Pig when running over yarn "org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: tasktracker3/10.201.2.169:50000"

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I am running Apache Pig 0.11.2 with Hadoop 2.2.0.

Most simple jobs that I run in Pig work perfectly fine.

However, whenever I try to use **GROUP BY** on a large dataset, or the **LIMIT** operator, I get these connection errors:

> 2013-12-18 11:21:28,400 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client -
>   Retrying connect to server: tasktracker2/10.201.2.145:54957. Already
>   tried 0 time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
>   2013-12-18 11:21:29,402 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client -
>   Retrying connect to server: tasktracker2/10.201.2.145:54957. Already
>   tried 1 time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
>   2013-12-18 11:21:30,403 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client -
>   Retrying connect to server: tasktracker2/10.201.2.145:54957. Already
>   tried 2 time(s); retry policy is
>   RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
>   2013-12-18 11:21:30,507 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is
>   completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job
>   history server 2013-12-18 11:21:31,703 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker1/10.201.2.20:49528. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:32,704 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker1/10.201.2.20:49528. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:33,705 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker1/10.201.2.20:49528. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:33,809 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is
>   completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job
>   history server 2013-12-18 11:21:34,890 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker3/10.201.2.169:50000. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:35,891 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker3/10.201.2.169:50000. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:36,893 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server:
>   tasktracker3/10.201.2.169:50000. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy
>   is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1
>   SECONDS) 2013-12-18 11:21:36,996 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is
>   completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job
>   history server 2013-12-18 11:21:37,152 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is
>   completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job
>   history server

The strange thing is that after these errors keeping appearing for about minutes, they'll stop, and the correct output shows up at the bottom.

So Hadoop is running fine and computing the proper output. The problem is just these connection errors that keep popping up. and that causing increase in execution time of the script.

One thing that I have noticed is that whenever this error appears, the job had created and ran multiple JAR files during the job. However, after a few minutes of these message popping up, the correct output finally appears.

I have 5 nodes cluster 1 namenode and 4 datanode. All the daemons are running fine.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of these messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your job history server is not running.

1. Turn on log aggregation (you may have already done that and you're only missing the server) - put this to your `yarn-site.xml`:

   ```
   <property>
      <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </property>
   ```
2. Run the job history server:

   ```
   $HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin/mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver
   ```
3. Try running the Pig script again